# Redirect function in html page with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I today visited this [Website Page](https://cbseneet.nic.in/cbseneet/online/ForgetPwd.aspx). There at top of the page 3 radio linked button. When I click on that surprised there was not Amy window loading function and I will Instant moved to second page as wish I click on radio button.

I also view that source code for ajax code but there was not available might.

I am also want to create same like that on my website when user click any links or button or input then, page never load it all done via like [linked](https://cbseneet.nic.in/cbseneet/online/ForgetPwd.aspx) page function.

Please help how I create like that code .
Please teach me in a example.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This tech called as "*Load page content via AJAX*". You can google search this keyword to know how it work.

And here is the working demo with **jQuery** javascript library. You can check my code and comment in *script* tag. (Click launch in editor, inside the "index.html" file)

Link : https://plnkr.co/IMHyUwI4zllOwlCXb6b5

Code :

```
/* When the DOM ready */
    $(document).ready(function() {
      /* Do */
      /* Load content to div has id = main, from url = 'r1.html' (default state for fisrt visit time)*/
      $('#main').load('r1.html');
      /* Find input with id = r1, bind to click event */
      $('#r1').on('click', function() {
        /* when it get clicked , load content to div has id = main, from url = 'r1.html' */
        $('#main').load('r1.html');
      });
      /* Find input with id = r2, bind to click event */
      $('#r2').on('click', function() {
        /* when it get clicked , load content to div has id = main, from url = 'r2.html' */
        $('#main').load('r2.html');
      });
      /* Find input with id = r3, bind to click event */
      $('#r3').on('click', function() {
        /* when it get clicked , load content to div has id = main, from url = 'r2.html' */
        $('#main').load('r3.html');
      });
    });
```

Comment: I appreciated that you share your explain. Who we can add this funtions in button or href tags? Is there any backend code available to that user not see in source code.pls reply

Comment: How we add your redirect page function inside this code `<div class="col_half forgot_pw" id="link">Forgot Password?</div>` ?

Comment: Just like in demo , listen to click event on div has id = **link**
Code : 
      $('#link').on('click',function(){ /* Do anything here */ });